# Given x gates, write loop to go through all possible gate combinations?

Tags: c

I am trying to print out the full truth table with a variable dependent number of inputs, but I cant figure out any algorithm to achieve that.
I want my function to look like this:

```
int report(CallBack myfunctions, int gates)
```

`CallBack` is a pointer to a function and `gates` is an integer reffering to the number of inputs.
For example typing `report(and, 3)` would produce this output

```
0000
0010
0100
0110
1000
1010
1100
1111
```

First 3 columns represent all possible combinations from the 3 inputs, 4th column contains the 'AND' result of each row.
My problem it that i cant find a way to go from one line to the next.
I've tried utilising the property of each number to be written as the sum of powers of 2 (eg. 14 = 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1) but I cant find a way to make it work for a large number of inputs because the number of columns increases accordingly.
NOTE: number of gates doesnt have to be infinite, up to 20 is enough

I should also point out that the AND function calculates the result through a linked list (as its only parameter) and each node of the linked list contains an input (eg. 0->1->1->0->0).

For the creation of the linked list i've made 2 functions (and heres the struct as well):

```
typedef struct data
{
    int value;
    struct data * next;
} Data;
typedef Data * DataList;

Data * createData(int value)
{
    Data * dataptr;
    dataptr = malloc(sizeof (Data));
    dataptr->value = value;
    dataptr->next = NULL;
    return dataptr;
}
void appendData(DataList *lstptr, Data *newptr)
{
    if (*lstptr==NULL)
    {
        *lstptr = newptr;
        return;
    }
    appendData( &((*lstptr)->next), newptr);
    return;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the list? Try two loops one nested in the other.

Comment: *"Is there a way to print out a full truth table in c?"* Yes, of course it is possible. Can you narrow this down? A lot. Ie. what is your specific problem here?

Comment: its the easiest way to pass a large amount of inputs into the function that i could think of

Comment: @hyde I guess the title was a bit too general, thats my bad, but I think I've clearly stated the problem I'm facing within the actual contents of my question

Comment: Is the question "given X gates, write loop to go through all possible gate combinations?" Because that is very quick to answer. But if the question is please write this function for me", then SO is a wrong please to ask.

Comment: Also unclear: is number of gates "unlimited", eg 1000 gates should be supported? Or is maximum gates 64 or less? (Though printing out the truth table for more than a few dozen gates is going to take too long time to ever complete).

Comment: its exactly the first thing u said, i'll edit the title to this, now I see what you meant in your previous comment, thanks. Also not its not unlimited, I'm not interested in surpassing for example 20 gates

Comment: Then you can use uint64_t for example. If linked list is not required, remove it and use `struct gates { unsigned count; uint64_t bits; };` Is it required?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is required

Comment: Well, there are so many ways to go about this. Given the linked list requirement, create function to create linked list of length X with all zeroes. Then create a function to add one to the *binary value* contained in the list, with overflow detection. Then simply `do { calculate and print result } while (increase gate list does not overflow)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *n* inputs, then you can achieve what you want as follows:

1. For i = 0 to 2^n-1,

   1. For j = 0 to n-1,

      1. Set inputs[j] to ( i >> k ) & 1.
   2. Do something with inputs.

---

A more complex approach that possibly does less work.<sup>[1]</sup>

1. Set overflow to 0.
2. For j = 0 to n-1,

   1. Set inputs[j] to 0.
3. Loop,

   1. Do something with inputs.
   2. Set j to 0.
   3. Loop,

      1. If inputs[j] is 0,

         1. Set inputs[j] to 1.
         2. Break out of loop.
      2. Else,

         1. Set inputs[j] to 0.
         2. Increment j.
         3. If j is equal to n,

            1. Set overflow to 1.
            2. Break out of loop.
   4. If overflow,

      1. Break out of loop.

---

Finally, another approach is to leave the bits in their "packed" form and pass them to the callback as an integer instead of an array.

1. For input = 0 to 2^n-1,

   1. Do something with input.

The callback for a 3-bit AND would look like this:

```c
int and3( uint64_t input ) {
   return input == 7 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

---

Footnotes.

1. It can also handle a larger number of inputs, but the first approach can already handle 64 inputs, which can't be completed by a modern computer.

Comment: Totally agree. Digital values should be packed together wherever possible, a computer is very good at bit operations.

Comment: @Neil and optimizing compilers are very good (and constantly rapidly getting better) at turning *clear logic* into whatever is most efficient for the given optimization goals on the target computer, but neither humans nor optimizing compilers are very good at reverse engineering from all possible results on all possible inputs that some arbitrary bit twiddling is actually semantically an operation on booleans.